# Are the Noor and the Lightforce the same thing?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, cloak-and-dagger, ms-marvel-2022

In *Cloak & Dagger*, the Lightforce is an energy from a "light" dimension, in contrast to the Darkforce from a "dark" dimension. Dagger (Tandy Bowen) can form the Lightforce into objects, such as daggers.

In *Ms. Marvel*, the Noor is an energy from a "light" dimension. Night Light / Ms. Marvel (Kamala Khan) can form the Noor into objects, such as platforms.

Is the Lightforce supposed to be the same as the Noor? Or are they entirely unrelated extra-dimensional light energies?

Comment: Purely based on the fact that [they're different colours](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/wandavision-finale-interview-aerospace-engineer-quicksilver-multiverse-matt-shakman/#362098_4), I'm going to say no.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite that's an article about WandaVision that doesn't mention either.

Comment: Correct, but it does describe some degree of colour-coding that the MCU has used for magic. So I'm suggesting that if they intended a link between Noor and the Lightforce, they might have made them look more similar.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite they are almost the same colour. Differences in the exact SFX can be down to different production companies - see also how the Darkhold was different between the Marvel Television and the Marvel Studios productions.

Comment: Oh, they are? I thought the Lightforce was bright white, like [this shard thingy](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/36/84/15/368415f66086e8ce7f830397a69e37bb--cloak-and-dagger-cloaks.jpg), and [this smaller shard thingy](https://comicyears.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/cloak-and-dagger-canceled-or-renewed.jpg).  (Whereas Noor looked to me like it had a [glowy purple-y thing](https://legendary-digital-network-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/20134127/Cool-shot-of-Ms.-Marvels-powers.jpg) going on.)

Comment: (I only saw season 1 of Cloak and Dagger, several years ago, so I may well be misremembering the Lightforce.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite or my display settings need adjusting